# significance of chains and antichains in partially ordered set

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can anyone help me with this question?
I was thinking chains give longest possible subsequence of of related elements in increasing order and antichains denotes number of elements which are not related. I am not getting that only this much is there or some more significant points are also there.

Answer (score 0):

The longest chain is the length of the order, the largest antichain is the width.  When finite they are related by Dilworths theorem.